# How can I use a command output results as the next command input information in gdb

Tags: gdb, pipe

I want to use a command part of the findings as a command input information

It couldn't seem to use pipe mechanism in gdb.

basically I need to emulate this

Code:

```
info symbol 0xffffffff
```

Automatic the output of above  as the below of input

```
info function xxxxxxxxx
```

in gdb.
Sometime,I want to use the part of the findings as a command input information ,So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this is via [Python scripting](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html).

Comment: ...Shell scripting is impossiable?

Comment: @choujayyl GDB is not a shell, so no.

Comment: I change the content,please review it and help me to slove it,thanks.